# Fix 'Unable to write into user settings" when adding material icon theme extension

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I setup vs code for flutter development and when I add material icon theme extension it give me an error "Unable to write into user settings".

In Setting.json
This line give error: ( "code-runner.executorMap": { )
It show error:        Expected commajsonc(514)

Comment: That usually means the previous setting dies not have a trailing comma, which is necessary between settings.

Answer (score 0):

simply change setting.json to this:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme":"Visual Studio 2019 Dark",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"javascript": "node",
"java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o 
$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"php": "php",
"python": "python -u",
"perl": "perl",
"perl6": "perl6",
"ruby": "ruby",
"go": "go run",
"lua": "lua",
"groovy": "groovy",
"powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
"bat": "cmd /c",
"shellscript": "bash",
"fsharp": "fsi",
"csharp": "scriptcs",
"vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
"typescript": "ts-node",
"coffeescript": "coffee",
"scala": "scala",
"swift": "swift",
"julia": "julia",
"crystal": "crystal",
"ocaml": "ocaml",
"r": "Rscript",
"applescript": "osascript",
"clojure": "lein exec",
"haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
"rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"racket": "racket",
"scheme": "csi -script",
"ahk": "autohotkey",
"autoit": "autoit3",
"dart": "dart",
"pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"haskell": "runhaskell",
"nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
"lisp": "sbcl --script",
"kit": "kitc --run",
"v": "v run",
"sass": "sass --style expanded",
"scss": "scss --style expanded",
"less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
"FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt 
&& $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
},
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.languageIdToFileExtensionMap": {

"bat": ".bat",
"powershell": ".ps1",
"typescript": ".ts"
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).